# Python selenium skip page if message element not visible skipping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, error-handling, web-scraping

I am trying to grab a text element from a page. To get to this element my scrips clicks on two filters on the page. I need to crawl 5,000 pages. The script works, in terms of collecting the text element, however, after a certain number of pages it always returns a message "element not visible". I am assuming it's due to the fact that page didn't load in time, since I checked the pages where it breaks and the text element is there. (I have time.sleep(3) already implemented after every click). What can I use in my script to just skip that page if it doesn't load in time?

```
def yelp_scraper(url):
    driver.get(url)
    # get total number of restaurants 
    total_rest_loc = '//span[contains(text(),"Showing 1")]'
    total_rest_raw = driver.find_element_by_xpath(total_rest_loc).text
    total_rest = int(re.sub(r'Showing 1.*of\s','',total_rest_raw))

    button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="filter-label filters-toggle js-all-filters-toggle show-tooltip"]')
    button1.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Walking (1 mi.)")]')
    button2.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    rest_num_loc = '//span[contains(text(),"Showing 1")]'
    rest_num_raw = driver.find_element_by_xpath(rest_num_loc).text
    rest_num = int(re.sub(r'Showing 1.*of\s','',rest_num_raw))

    if total_rest==rest_num:

        button3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Biking (2 mi.)")]')
        button3.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        button4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Walking (1 mi.)")]')
        button4.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        rest_num_loc = '//span[contains(text(),"Showing 1")]'
        rest_num_raw = driver.find_element_by_xpath(rest_num_loc).text
        rest_num = int(re.sub(r'Showing 1.*of\s','',rest_num_raw))


    return(rest_num)


chromedriver = "/Applications/chromedriver" # path to the chromedriver executable
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver


chrome_options = Options()
# add headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# turn off image loading
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)


for url in url_list:
    yelp_data[url] = yelp_scraper(url)

json.dump(yelp_data, open('../data/yelp_json/yelp_data.json', 'w'), indent="\t")


driver.close()
```

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: I included it above

Answer (score 1):

- EXAMPLE:

  ```
      from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
      for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item'):
          try:
          model = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
          price = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
          title = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-title')
          url = item.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

          items.append({'model': model, 'price': price, 'title': title, 'url': url})
          print (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
          c = (model.text, price.text, title.text, url.get_attribute("href"))
          a.writerow(c)
      except NoSuchElementException:
  #here you can do what you want to do when an element is not found. Then it'll continue with the next one. 
  b.close()
  ```

Comment: Missing explanatory text. Bots will find your answer insufficient so post text so we can learn from it. End of Review.